# XPath: Assign a sibling's child's attribute to another node

Tags: xml, xpath, localization, translation

I want to create a custom parser rule with XPath which satisfies the following conditions. Let's say my file consists of many instances of this code:

```
 <trans-unit id="01">
  <source>Test</source>
  <target>Test</target>
  <context-group name=" extract">
   <context context-type="x-length"> 10 PX </context>
  </context-group>
 </trans-unit>
```

I want to parse the  node with an "x-length" attribute as the length restriction rule for the target node under the same trans-unit node.

How do I go about it? In most examples I've researched about length restriction, the character limit is shown as an attribute of the node that you want to select for translation, like this one

```
<salutation limit="40">Dear Daniel,</salutation>
```

My case is a bit different, though. The `<target>` node is sibling to the `<context-group>` node, so how do I assign an attribute from a sibling's child node to another sibling node? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if you have a major misconception about what XPath does or just a minor terminology misunderstanding, but **XPath is about *selection*, not *assignment***.

Comment: In fact, your terminology here is altogether confusing. Nodes don't get parsed: they are produced as the output of a parser. I've no idea what a "custom parser rule" might be used for. What does a "length restriction rule" do? What has this to do with localization or translation? What do you actually want from your XPath expression?

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. And yes, I am kind of new to this, but I should have mentioned this has to do with using cat tools for importing xml elements, more specifically SDL studio. The idea is to use a custom file type which imports (or parses) elements and attributes from the .xml file using xpath expressions. Hopefully, that should make more sense. Though admittedly, I am not sure what I am asking is even possible with Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//context[@context-type="x-length"]
```

will select all `context` elements with `@context-type` attribute values of `"x-length"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for unique result of above sample code"

```
//context-group[@name=' extract']//context[@context-type="x-length"]
```